# Higher-order unification for type constructor inference

Tags: scala

```
def meh[M[_], A](x: M[A]): M[A] = x
meh((x: Int) => "")
```

After SI-2712 (https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712) fix type A is inferred to the rightmost type parameter. In my example for Function1[Int,String] it is String.

How to make it inferred to left parameter?

And why this approach is not working?

```
class T[K,M]{}

def inferToLeft[S[_,_],K,B](ot: S[K,B]):({type Op[T] = S[T,B]})#Op[K]= ot

meh(inferToLeft(new T[Int,String]))
```

It's still inferred to String instead of Int

Comment: I guess I could find an answer for the first part of my question: there was Unapply class in cats and scalaz that used to "fix" this issue and allowed both left-to-right and right-to-left partial unifications. As a "left-to-right" case is a quite rare, Unapply was removed from cats library. SI-2712 doesn't allow left-to-right unification. For this purpose Unapply class from scalaz or kittens projects should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler prefers to expand types that don't have a stable name ASAP (I don't know the rationale for that, sorry), so your type lambda at the return spot is simplified before call to `meh`. The good news is that you can use unification to your advantage to generalize it:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime._, universe._
import scala.language.higherKinds

def checkUnification[F[_], A: TypeTag](fa: => F[A]) = s"${typeOf[A]}"

implicit class InferToLeft[M[_, _], A, B](a: M[A, B]) {
  def lefty: InferToLeft.U[M, B, A] = a
}

object InferToLeft {
  type U[M[_, _], B, A] = M[A, B]
}

def e: Either[Int, String] = ???
def f: AnyRef => List[Int] = ???

assert(checkUnification(e) == "String")
assert(checkUnification(e.lefty) == "Int")
assert(checkUnification(f) == "scala.List[Int]")
assert(checkUnification(f.lefty) == "AnyRef")
```

Here the type `InferToLeft.U` is available at a stable path, so your argument is passed as `U[M, B, A]` without simplification, making unification pick `A`, which is the left argument of your type constructor.

Comment: Don't forget to set the `-Ypartial-unification` flag to make this work.