# Higher degrees of higher kinded types?

Tags: scala, haskell, traits, typeclass, higher-kinded-types

I just recently learned about higher kinded types, but every example I was presented with only used a degree-2 kind `(* -> *) -> *`, like `Functor`.

In Scala, a weird **trait** definition is used, and in Haskell, **type classes** are used. And both approaches seem like they cannot work with one degree of abstraction more (i.e. `((* -> *) -> *) -> *`).

I am neither an expert in Scala nor Haskell, so it would be helpful if you could provide **simple** examples of such higher degree types, if they are expressible at all.

Comment: "both approaches seem like they cannot work with one degree of abstraction more" - why do you believe so? (Aside: may be better to focus on traits or type classes, not both - they are entirely different beasts).

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370444/what-types-of-problems-helps-higher-kinded-polymorphism-solve-better

Answer (score 6):

```
trait Functor[F[_]] //has kind (* -> *) -> *

trait Functor[A[B[_]]] //has kind ((* -> *) -> *) -> *

trait Map[A[_],B[_]] //has kind (* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> *
```

***Edit:***

You can investigate kinds by yourself by calling "kind" command in REPL:

scala> :kind -v Map

Comment: So in your second example: A and B are concrete type constructor names, not type variables, right?

Comment: they are abstract. Such Functor type doesn't not exist but if you create trait like this it would have kind ((* -> *) -> *) -> * .  And compiler would take care about checking that all A-typed parameters has kind (* -> *) -> *. Like def doSomething(a: A) would compile only with values like List(List(1,3))

Comment: Is there any difference between an abstract name like `A` and the underscore `_`? Or does the latter simply mean „I don‘t care about the name because I don‘t use it in the implementation.“?

Comment: correct. And you can even create trait Functor[ _ [ _ [ _ ] ] ] having the same kind  ((* -> *) -> *) -> *

Comment: Ah, so is `_` therefore an existential type? And: Is a higher kinded type still just a type that I can use anywhere a type is required?

Comment: yes its existential type. You can use anywhere where type of this kind is required and in some advanced cases even when different kind required (see this quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263931/higher-order-unification-for-type-constructor-inference )

Comment: if your method accepts A type you can pass all higher kinded types there, but if you have A[ _ ] you need exactly * -> * except for advanced usage based on SI-2712 fix

Comment: OK, regarding this: Is there any sort of substitution principle for kinds? Like `* -> *` conforms to `*` or `(* -> *) -> *` conforms to `* -> *` and `*`?

Comment: it looks something like this: if you have higher kinded type parameter you must passe at least this kind or higher. It meas if you have * -> * you need at least A[ _ ] but in place of "_" there can be higher kinded type as well. So in case * -> * required on the place of first star you can put any type including higher kinded type. In other words: if you stated that type has a kind you need to provide this kind. In case of A[ B ] I stated that A has a kind but B doesn't, so I can pass type of any kind instead of B

Comment: you can check with Array for example. It has kind * -> * (Array[T]) but you can pass any-kinded-type instead of T. You just can't use benefits of knowing kind of T inside Array because T has no kind difined. But for Array functionality it's not a problem.

Comment: Awesome! I wonder if I'm ever in a situation where I have a **concrete value** that is statically known to have type of kind `* -> *` (or higher). **How can it come into existence**? Let's say I have a variable of type `Array`. What can I do with it? Can I call `.count()` on it? Or must the type of any concrete value always be fully-constructed, but maybe containing an existential type parameter, like `Array[_]`? `Array[_]` is quite different than `Array`, right? The former has kind `*` (i.e. fully-constructed, but with unknown parts), the latter has kind `* -> *` (i.e. not fully-constructed).

Comment: not sure if I understand you, but you will probably be interested in reading this https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html . BTW: you can't have variable of type Array it can be subtype of Array constructed by type constructor only.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I just flew over it. Let me pin-point my question with a simple example: Can I write an Identity function that takes a higher-kinded argument, and just returns it, with a signature like this: `id(A[_] argument)`, where `A` is some abstract type constructor?

Comment: I guess you mean something like this:     def id[A[ _ ]](x: A[ _ ]): A[ _ ]  = x

Comment: Yeah, so in this case, does `A[_]` have kind `*` or `* -> *`? I.e. is `_` an existential type or a type parameter placeholder?

Comment: it is existential type. The kind of A[_] is * -> *. I can rewrite it without existential type: def id[A[B],B](x: A[B]): A[B]  = x . In this case I can use B  type inside the def if needed.

Comment: Some people use "type" to mean "thing that classifies a value". Other people use it more loosely to mean "any expression in the language of *type-formers* used right of `::`, but I wish they wouldn't, because it causes the confusion we see here. All types (meaning those things which classify values) have kind `*`. All types are type-formers but not all type-formers are types: type-formers have a variety of kinds. There is no such thing as a value with a type of higher kind, because there is no such thing as a type of higher kind.

Comment: @pigworker: Yeah this sounds reasonable to me. But then, the type of argument `x` in the function in the example, `def id[A[_]](x: A[_]): A[_] = x`, simply has kind `*`. But the expression `A[_]` does not denote a type, but rather a type-former of kind `* -> *`. It only becomes a type once a caller of `id` provides an actual instantiation of `A[_]`, correct?

Comment: For clarification, because I don't think anyone truly answered it in the above comments, in the second example, `A` is a type constructor that is visible inside the definition of `Functor`. `B` is just a name given to that parameter, but is only in scope in the declaration of `A`. `trait Functor[A[B[_]]] { def b: B[Int] }` is invalid, but `Functor[A[B[_]] <: B[Int]]` isn't. You can replace `B` with `_` as in `Functor[A[_[_]]]`, but not as in `Functor[A[_[_]] <: _[Int]]`, as that removes the relationship between `A`'s argument and the bound. Analogy: `trait T[F[X] <: Seq[X]]`/`trait T[F[_]]`.

Comment: @HTNW: What about this: `trait Functor[A[B[_]], B[_]] { def b: B[Int] }`. Can be very precise about what exactly the symbols `A` and `B` are (both in my and your example)? What exactly is different in my definition as compared to yours (`trait Functor[A[B[_]]] { def b: B[Int] }`)?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the Scala syntax, but it looks to me as if `A[_]` is used in two subtly different ways. In `id[A[_]]`, it indicates parametrisation by a type-former. In the return type of `id` and the type of `x`, `A[_]` refers to an arbitrary instantiation of that type-former to a type. In Haskell, we'd have `forall (a :: * -> *)(x :: *). a x -> a x`, which makes clearer the abstraction over first a type-former, then an arbitrary parameter for that type-former.

Comment: @MightyNicM from the practical perspective, as mentioned HTNW,  the difference between trait Functor[A[B[ _ ]], B[ _ ]] and trait Functor[A[B[ _ ]]] is that you can or can't use B type inside the definition of trait Functor. Both A and B are abstract types. I guess we need such trick because of type erasure in JVM. At runtime A[B[ _ ]] will be replaced to SomeRealType[Object] .. so we probably need some extra hint for JVM for understand real type of B ... but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @MightNicM No. The `B` in the first parameter is *out of scope* by the time you define it in the second. The first parameter and second parameter are totally unrelated, and it makes no sense to compare semantics between mine and yours, because mine is semantically *nonsense*. Think about it: what would `trait T[A[B[_]]] { def b: B[Int] }` even mean? That's like trying to write a function `f[A,B]: (B => A) => B`.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko No, erasure has nothing to do with this. `B` isn't a parameter to *you*; it's the parameter to `A`. *You __set__* `B` by passing an argument to `A`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for helping me understand at least the important concepts involved here, and to reduce the overall confusion.

Answer (score 6):

In Scala(Z), the obvious higher-kind type is the `MonadTrans` trait:

```
trait MonadTrans[F[_ [_], _]] { ... }
```

Its kind is `T->*`, where `T` is the kind of its parameter `F`.

`F` is a monad transformer, and `T` is the kind of all monad transformers. Recall that a monad transformer is parametrised by a monad and its "output" is another monad, so its kind is `(*->*) -> (*->*)` (or, equivalently, `(*->*) -> * -> *`). So the kind of `MonadTrans` is

```
((*->*) -> * -> *) -> *
```

In Haskell there are no traits, and type classes are not types, so `MonadTrans` is out as a non-type. There is a type that represents a composition of monad transformers though:

```
newtype ComposeT f g m a = ...
```

Here's its full definition from `Control.Monad.Trans.Compose`:

```
newtype ComposeT (f :: (* -> *) -> * -> *) (g :: (* -> *) -> * -> *) m a
    = ComposeT { getComposeT :: f (g m) a }
```

Quite a mouthful! `f` and `g` are monad transformers (as can be seen from their explicitly given signatures), `m` is a monad (signature `* ->*` is not given explicitly but implied by `g m`), and `a` is a regular type of kind `*`. So the overall kind of `ComposeT` is:

```
((* -> *) -> * -> *) ->
((* -> *) -> * -> *) ->
 (* -> *) -> * -> *
```